# How to get the list of indices created in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I was able to retrieve the indices from Elasticsearch and register the corresponding index pattern in Kibana programmatically in Java. Now I would like to get the list of the index patterns already created in Kibana so that I could cross check it against the index list from Elasticsearch so as to not create them again in Kibana.

Is there an API to fetch the index pattern list from Kibana?

--

API for getting the list of indices from Elasticsearch:

`http://{hostname}:{port}/_aliases`

API for creating an index pattern in Kibana:

`http://{hostname}:{port}/{kibana instance Id}/index-pattern/{index pattern title}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the next query:
GET /.kibana/index-pattern/_search

Comment: seems to be returning the patterns ... Thanks!

Comment: On further testing when I deleted one index pattern from Kibana, the API did not return me the correct results.

Comment: How did you delete the index pattern?

Comment: Using the UI in Kibana.

Comment: You said that the query didn't return the correct result, do you mean that you got the index pattern that you delete before?

Comment: Yes. I had two index patterns registered in Kibana. Using the API I was able to get those two patterns. But when I deleted one of them then also the API returned two index patterns.

Comment: Which elasticsearch version?

Comment: My bad, I am using a custom index say, .kibana_<id> to register the index patterns. Hence in the case when I used the default .kibana, it did not work. Now everything is working fine at my end. Thanks for the answers Lax.

Answer (score 1):

This query works (from kibana dev console):

```
GET .kibana/_search?size=10000
{
  "_source": ["index-pattern.title"],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "type": "index-pattern"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for kibana 7.x:

- Get all index patterns

```bash
curl -s 'http://192.168.100.100:5601/api/saved_objects/_find?fields=title&fields=type&per_page=10000&type=index-pattern'

# Use jq to get the index-pattern name:
curl -s 'http://192.168.100.100:5601/api/saved_objects/_find?fields=title&fields=type&per_page=10000&type=index-pattern' | jq '.saved_objects[].attributes.title'

"service01"
"service02"
"service03"
```

- DELETE specific index pattern

```bash
curl -XDELETE -H 'kbn-xsrf: ""' 'http://192.168.100.100:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/970070d0-f252-11ea-b492-31ec85db4535'
```

`-H 'kbn-xsrf: ""'` must be set or the API will complain `{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Request must contain a kbn-xsrf header."}`

use `jq -r` to get the value without qoute.

Comment: This works in Kibana 7.17 and 8.2. For reference, the documented [find objects API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.2/saved-objects-api-find.html) in the Kibana 8.2 docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it still isn't available at the moment, where you could use an api to expose all the indexes which are being created in `Kibana`.

But keep in mind that you'll be able to create an index in `Kibana`, only if you've already created the indice in ES. So maybe you could consider checking your ES indices whether you've already got an existing one, if not create the index. Where you can make sure that, if the index isn't existing in your indices list, which means that there's no way that you would've went on and created an index in `Kibana`.

Comment: Thanks Kulasangar. This is what I am doing right now. I am checking the indices in ES and is using those only which matches the item/s in the probable list (in memory) of patterns. The thing is I don't want to be creating those already created index patterns in Kibana again the next time when I repeat the process.

Comment: @lex What're you're trying to do is absolutely right. Lets hope for an enhancement in the future. If my answer had helped you vote it up, if it had guided to your requirement mark it as an answer so that it might help the others as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can list them from the API:

`GET _cat/indices/.marvel*
GET _cat/indices/.kibana`

Comment: using 
```
GET _cat/indices/.kibana
``` 
gives me 
``` green open .kibana 1 0 2 0 6.6kb 6.6kb ```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Kibana (version 5.5) console and could get the same by doing this query

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":10000}'  \
 http://$ES_HOST/.kibana/index-pattern/_search/\?stored_fields\=""
```

Please note that making a GET request to the above url as below will also return the fields, but they are limited to 10.

```
curl http://$ES_HOST/.kibana/index-pattern/_search/\?stored_fields\=""
```